# PHP to MS SQL Undefined Index Error

Tags: php, html, sql-server, forms

I am having an error populating a column in my sql table from my php form. I am getting an Undefined index: ID error. First I will show you my php/html code which displays all my data correctly, I will show screen shots, and then I will show the incorrect populating of answers in my sql table. Thank you for looking and the assistance!

This first code is where I create my selection which is working correctly, I believe because everything that I am importing from my sql table shows up properly.

```
<label for="animalCommony">Common Name</label>
<select name="animalCommony" id="animalCommony" form="form1">
<option>Select a Common Name:</option>

<?php
$db = get_db_connection('swcrc');
$db->connect();
$db->query("SELECT [Common Name] FROM dbo.All_Animals"); //THE BRACKETS WORK FINE I WILL SHOW
                                                         //A SCREEN SHOT OF THE FUNCTIONAL FORM
while($row = $db->fetch())
{
?>
   <option value="<?php echo $row['ID'];?>"><?php echo $row[`Common Name`];?></option> //THIS IS
   //WHERE I BELIEVE THE ERROR MAYBE COMING FROM THIS IS LINE 570
<?php 
}
?>
</select>
</p>
```

This next part of code is where I am inserting my select answers into my MS SQL table *NOTE* everything is populating in my MS SQL table properly except for my animalCommoner variable.

```
 $animalClasser = (isset($_POST['animalClassy'])? $_POST['animalClassy']: null);
 $animalCommoner = (isset($_POST['animalCommony'])? $_POST['animalCommony']:null); //NOT 
        //POPULATING INTO MS SQL DATABASE
        $db->query("UPDATE dbo.Request SET status='%s' WHERE ID=%d", 
            $_POST['completed'],
            $_POST['request_id']);
        $db->query("INSERT INTO dbo.Response (request_ID, user_ID, complete, comment,
                                              response_date, animalClass, animalCommon) 
        VALUES (%d, %d, '%s', 's', 's', '$animalClasser', '$animalCommoner')",
            $_POST['request_id'], 
            $_POST['completed_by_user_id'], 
            $_POST['completed'], 
            $_POST['not_completed'],
            $_POST['date_completed']);
```

Next I will post a screen show of the incorrectly populated sql table. It's a very thin picture.
[image]

Finally I will post a screen shot of my form to show that it is populating correctly.
[image]

Thank you for looking and helping!
THIS IS THE BLOWN UP MESSAGE OF THE ERROR
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The undefined index is showing up because the key you using in your array was not retrieved with the query. Your current query only selects the value [Common Name] from the table, so 'Common Name' is going to be the only key available for each row. If ID is a column in your table, try changing your query to be something like this:

```
$db->query("SELECT [ID], [Common Name] FROM dbo.All_Animals");
```

Comment: Thank you for the response Shane, I made the change you suggested but I am still receiving the same error, sadly.